# sscanf is unable to scan a string that is given inside quotes

Tags: c, string, scanf, quotes

So the concept is this: I want to scan a maximum of 5 strings at a time but it is possible to want to scan just one. This is the point of sscanf,I don't always want to type in 5 things through the console. One line could mean the input of one string or all 5. The problem is when I type:

```
remove "Just Test"
```

I get my first string normally,but I end up getting my second string "split" between string1 (now it is:`"Just`) and string2 (now it is:`Test"`). This is the code for reference:

```
fgets(inputbuffer,500,stdin);
sscanf(inputbuffer,"%s %s %s %s %[^\n]s",action,string1,string2,string3,string4);
```

The problem seems to come from the space between Just and Test. I managed to fix this problem for `string4` by putting `[^\n]`,which reads everything till the newline. As you can tell though,this wont obviously work for `string1`/`string2`/`string3`. I am in a pretty tight space cause of this and I am not sure what to do.

Comment: OT: `%[^\n]s` is not what you want, `%[^\n]` is.

Comment: `sscanf` is doing exactly what it's supposed to do, `%s` specifier parses one word and that includes all readable characters except for white spaces, if you want to treat "Just Test" as a single word you need to code this yourself, there is no out of the box way of doing it, AFAICT.

Comment: Please explain which 5 strings you expect to scan from an input of `"remove \"Just Test\""`.

Comment: Hey everybody,with the assistance of a friend of mine,this is the new correct-for-my-purpose sscanf function line:
```sscanf(inputbuffer,"%s \"%[^\"]\" %s \"%[^\"]\" \"%[^\"]\"",action,string1,string2,string3,string4);```